# Error (10170): expecting "<=", or "=", or "+=", or "-=", or "*=", or "/=", or "%=", or "&=", or "|=", or "^=", etc

Tags: syntax-error, verilog, hdl, intel-fpga, accumulator

```
module accumulator (
    input [7:0] A ,
    input reset,
    input clk,
    output reg carryout,
    output reg overflow,
    output reg [8:0] S,
    output reg HEX0,
    output reg HEX1,
    output reg HEX2,
    output reg HEX3
    );

    reg signA;
    reg signS;
    reg [7:0] magA;
    reg [7:0] magS;
    reg Alarger;

    initial begin
        S = 9'b000000000;
    end

    always_ff @ (posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
        if (reset) begin
            S = 9'b000000000;
        end
        else begin

            begin
            signA <= A[7];              //Is A negative or positive
            signS <= S[7];
            S <= A + S;
            end

            if (signA == 1) begin           //A is negative so magnitude is of 2s compliment
                magA <= (~A[7:0] + 1'b1);
            end
            else begin
                magA <= A;
            end

            if (signS == 1) begin           //sum is negative so magnitude is of 2s compliment
                magS <= (~S[7:0] + 1'b1);
            end
            else begin
                magS <= S;
            end

            if (magA > magS) begin
                Alarger <= 1'b1;        //Magnitude of A is larger than magnitude of sum
            end
            else begin
                Alarger <= 1'b0;
            end

            if ((signA == 1) & (Alarger == 1) & (S[7] == 0)) begin
                overflow <= 1'b1;
            end
            else begin
                overflow <= 1'b0;
            end
            if ((signS == 1) & (Alarger == 0) & (S[7] == 0)) begin
                overflow <= 1'b1;
            end
            else begin
                overflow <= 1'b0;
            end
            if ((signS == 1) & (signA == 1) & (S[7] == 0)) begin
                overflow <= 1'b1;
            end
            else begin
                overflow <= 1'b0;
            end
            if ((signS == 0) & (signA == 0) & (S[7] == 1)) begin
                overflow <= 1'b1;
            end
            else begin
                overflow <= 1'b0;
            end
            if (S[8] == 1) begin            //carryout occurred
                carryout <= 1'b1;
                overflow <= 1'b0;
                S <= 9'b000000000;      //sum no longer valid
            end
            else begin
                carryout <= 1'b0;
            end

            display_hex h1                  //display of A
            (
                .bin            (magA),
                .hexl           (HEX2),
                .hexh           (HEX3)
            );

            display_hex h2                  //display of sum
            (
                .bin            (S[7:0]),
                .hexl           (HEX0),
                .hexh           (HEX1)
            );
        end
    end

endmodule
```

I am trying to make an accumulator that adds A (8 digit binary value that can be signed or unsigned) repeatedly to the sum.  Once the sum is computed, then sum and A should display the value on 4 hex display LEDs (2 LEDs for A and 2 LEDs for sum).  However, I am having a hard time getting it to compile.  I have searched the error code and it seems like a general error for a syntax error and can have several meanings.

Comment: You should not define submodules inside the `always` block.

Comment: Just to note that `-` performs twos complement ie `~S[7:0] + 1'b1 == -S[7:0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the exact error, but moving the instantiations of `display_hex` outside `always_ff` resolves the main issue:

```
module accumulator
(
    /* ... */
);
    // ...

    always_ff @ (posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
        /* ... */
    end

    display_hex h1 (
        /* ... */
    );

    display_hex h2 (
        /* ... */
    );
endmodule
```

Another thing: The code drives variable S from `initial` as well as `always`. This creates multiple drivers and the code will not compile. To fix this, remove the initial completely, you don't need it since `S` will be set to 0 when `reset` is asserted.

OR

You can move all the logic into the initial block; it'd look something like this (but this, most probably, won't synthesize):

```
initial begin
    S = 0;

    forever begin
        wait @(posedge clock);

        // Do stuff here ..
    end
end
```

Comment: You can have multiple drivers of variables, and `S` is a variable type (`reg`) so, its fine to have an `initial` block like this.

Comment: Maybe it's compiler dependent; doesn't compile on mine unless i purge the initial block

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: @Unn single driver is a requirement for `always_ff` as per [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) 9.2.2.4: "The `always_ff` procedure imposes the restriction that it contains one and only one event control and no blocking timing controls. Variables on the left-hand side of assignments within an `always_ff` procedure, including variables from the contents of a called function, shall not be written to by any other process." FPGA's may have deviated from the standard to allow an exception with `initial`

Comment: @Greg I always think of the FPGA except around `initial` and forgot those extra restrictions on `always_ff` versus a regular `always` block. Thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is the result of these two lines:

```
display_hex h1                  //display of A
(
  .bin            (magA),
  .hexl           (HEX2),
  .hexh           (HEX3)
);

display_hex h2                  //display of sum
(
  .bin            (S[7:0]),
  .hexl           (HEX0),
  .hexh           (HEX1)
);
```

Here, it appears you have a module named `display_hex` which converts an 8-bit value into the needed digits for a seven segment display. You are trying to use the module as if it were a function and modules are very much NOT functions. Modules in Verilog (or SystemVerilog as you are using, but the difference is really token at this point) can be though of as a group of hardware that takes in some inputs and spits out some outputs; and its important to note that they are static things. They either exist in the design or they do not; just like using ICs on a breadboard. The top module is the breadboard and the modules you declare under that module are components you are plugging into the board. The inputs and outputs are the various connections (pins) you must wire up to make everything work.

That said, always blocks (like the `always_ff` you are using) form a way of describing the logic and registers inside modules. Thus, you do thinks like assign `logic`/`reg` variables inside them to describe how the hardware behaves. If you look at your logic, you'll notice that the module declarations are dependent on `reset`; ie if `reset` is asserted, these modules wont exist, which doesnt make any sense. Electrical signals don't make entire ICs in a circuit disappear! Thus, you need to pull your module declaration out of your logical description of your acculumator, like so:

```
module accumulator (
  ...
  );
  ...
  display_hex h1                  //display of A
    (
      .bin            (magA),
      .hexl           (HEX2),
      .hexh           (HEX3)
    );

  display_hex h2                  //display of sum
    (
      .bin            (S[7:0]),
      .hexl           (HEX0),
      .hexh           (HEX1)
    );
  ...
  always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
    // Your accumulator logic here
    ...
  end
endmodule
```

Notice that the module declarations for the `display_hex` modules are stand alone, as I am declaring these modules exist, not dependence on anything!

However, there are a number of issues with your design besides that:

1. As you are using SystemVerilog constructs (`always_ff`), you should declare all of your variables type `logic`, not `reg` or left blank (ie, `input clk` should be `input logic clk`, `reg signA` should be `logic signA`). The `logic` type just makes everything easier, so use it :)
2. In your `always_ff` block, you do `reset` correctly except that the assignment should really be NBA (use `S <= 9'b0;`, not `S = 9'b0;` in the `if (reset)`)
3. You use NBA inside your `always_ff`, which is correct, however, it appears you need to use these values right away in the following logic. This will not work as you expect, or at least it will not act within the same clock cycle. To fix this, youll need to decide what should be a register and what should just be values resulting from intermediate logic, then create a separate `always_comb` for the intermediate values.
4. I am making the assumption that the `HEX` variables are meant for seven segment displays, so they should probably declared at least `[6:0] HEXn`